# jQuery Syntax, mouseover & timeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, hover, mouseover

I'm working on JQuery for the first time and am trying to implement script for an element which will expand 'on mouse enter' to 50px. After the mouse has hovered for 1 second or more it should expand to a further 190px. Finally when the mouse leaves the location it should resize back down to 35px. If the mouse leaves the location before it has fully expanded to 190px it should not continue to that step.

The code I have developed so far allows the element to expand, but if the mouse is removed the element is sized up to 190px regardless of time hovered.

I realise that I will most likely need to use a timeout function or some sort of if statement here, however I'm having problems adding it to the original code;

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element").on("mouseenter", function() {
     $(this).animate({"width": "50px"})
//DELAY 100MS, IF THE MOUSE IS STILL HOVERED THEN PROCEED
    .animate({"width": "190px"});
//ELSE CONTINUE WITH MOUSE LEAVE FUNCTION
     }).on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(this).animate({"width": "35px"});
  });
 });
```

Like I mentioned, I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax for this and after reading through other questions I'm getting more confused; which would be best to use? timeouts, .hover, if statement etc.?

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3gl8z3blFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `setTimeout` function for 1 second timeout before second animation:

```js
$("#element").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).animate({width: 50});        
    $(this).data('hover-timeout', setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).animate({width: 190});
    }.bind(this), 1000));
})
.on("mouseleave", function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hover-timeout'));
    $(this).stop(true).animate({width: 35});
});
```

```css
#element {
    background-color: #AAA;
    width: 35px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: Lovely addition to original code thanks for that.

I've also added further attributes which allow for an image source to be changed when the mouse is rolled over; here's the code:

Comment: `$("#element1").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).animate({width: 50}).children('img').attr('src', 'images/cl.png');
    $(this).data('hover-timeout', setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).animate({width: 190}); 
    }.bind(this), 500));
})
.on("mouseleave", function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hover-timeout'));
    $(this).stop(true).animate({width: 35}).children('img').attr('src', 'images/bw.png');
});`

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you have a delay function. The best would be to take a look in doc http://api.jquery.com/delay/